# Replacing the character on console with some other character

Tags: c, windows

I write a program that prints "**fb**" on console.
What I want is, When user press 9 then **b** gets replaced by **9**.
here is my code to print.

```
#include<conio.h> 

void main() 
{ 
    int r,c; 
    char ch;
    clrscr(); 
    for(r=0;r<=24;r++) //Fills rows 0 to 24 
        for(c=0;c<=79;c++) //Fills columns 0 to 79 
            printf("fb",1); 
    ch=getch(); 
}
```

I have no idea about the second part.

Comment: What's `printf("fb",1)` supposed to do? Is it your intention to write "fb" to the screen 25*80 times?

Comment: What are the `for` loops for?

Comment: this print fb on whole screen.

Comment: Please format your code.

Comment: If you want to write to arbitrary positions on the console, or even learn what size the console is (it may not be 25x80), you'll need to use the "curses" library or something similar.

Comment: The size of the "whole screen" could change with a flick of the mouse. And when you say, *What I want is, When user press 9 then b gets replaced by 9*, do you mean ALL of the `b`'s on the screen?

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker the problem i'm facing right now is how to replace b by 9 when user press 9 on keyboard.

Comment: @lurker yes, this is what i want.

Comment: Then you need a library. The C language doesn't do screen painting, it only does I/O streams.

Comment: Is it possible using interrupt handling, or writing keyboard buffer etc?

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker Asker is using the library associated with the header file `conio.h`.

Comment: Ah, that's a Windows thing, not C. From what I can tell, it doesn't provide any way to do what he wants either. I'm sure somebody must make a curses-like library for Windows?

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker yes that is a windows thing. can't we use system prograaming to achieve this?

Comment: You still haven't given much context here. Is this a Console program under Windows?

Comment: Sorry, I don't do Windows. Haven't a clue.

Answer (score 0):

Despite your useless for loops, you can realise this step with an if-statement. Try to ask if ch is the input you made, in your case **9**. Then you can clear the console screen and print out the **9**. For example:`if(ch == 9){
          system("cls"); //for linux: system("clear");
          printf("9\r\n");
        }`

By the way your main function should return an integer.

Good luck!